# How do I change what property to use in function of action based off of sender in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

```
@IBOutlet weak var weekdaysHoursSliderOutlet: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var weekdaysHoursLabelOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weekdaysHoursNumberLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var weekdendsHoursSliderOutlet: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var weekendsHoursLabelOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weekendsHoursNumberLabel: UILabel!


@IBAction func weekendsHoursSliderChange(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let currentValue: Int = Int(sender.value)
    weekendsHoursNumberLabel.text = ("\(currentValue)")

    if(currentValue == 1){
        weekendsHoursLabelOutlet.text = ("Hour Per Day")
    }
    else{
        weekendsHoursLabelOutlet.text = ("Hours Per Day")
    }
}
```

I would want to change that to weekdays if say the weekdaysHourSliderOutlet called an on change Action. I plan on implementing more than just weekends and weekdays so I don't want a bunch of redundant code. I was thinking of using a dictionary of some sort but couldn't get it hooked up correctly. Thank you in advance!

Comment: "but couldn't get it hooked up correctly": show what you have tried.

Comment: If the code needed for the two sliders is completely different, give each slider its own action.

Answer (score 0):

```
func viewDidLoad() {
     weekdaysHoursSliderOutlet.tag = 1
     weekdendsHoursSliderOutlet.tag = 2
}

@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
     if sender.tag == 1 {
          //handle weekdaysHoursSliderOutlet
     }
     else {
          //handle weekdendsHoursSliderOutlet
     }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you would set the tags in the storyboard, not in code.

Comment: ^ true dat, @rmaddy

Comment: Even better than using tags would be to compare `sender` to the outlet. `if sender === weekdaysHoursSliderOutlet { } else { }`.

Comment: Is there a way to make these comparisons in line so I don't have to duplicate things such as .text = ("\(currentValue)") ? I'm just trying to learn how to make my code as non-redundant as possible.

Comment: @JaredOwens I think you are looking for tertiary operator.   text = sender.tag == 1 ? "one" : "two"